# The document "xxx.dae" could not be saved

Tags: xcode, 3d, blender, arkit

EDIT: As of Xcode 11.1 everything is working.

I'm adding a 3D model originally downloaded from Sketchfab, to my ARKit application. The model does show up in my scene, though it has no material applied. No matter what I do, the file in my Xcode project is un-savable.

The original file from Sketchfab comes down in .obj format. After unzipping, I import it in Blender, update the origin and export it as a .dae. The file's owner and group changes in each step of the process and I am taking steps to ensure it is my user and group who has ownership of the file.

The current file permissions on my .dae file are "-rwxrwxrwx@" I am unsure how much more permission I can give. The @ means extended file permissions which is common for Xcode project files.

It would be amazing if I could apply my textures, normals and get on with my project.

Comment: The permissions on the parent folder/s can also prevent creating or saving a file.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I have tried changing the permissions on everything I could change including resetting the HD file permissions. I wound up making changes and exporting the file from xcode. Then Xcode would notice the file changed and I would click revert. Not pretty but I am out of the weeds.

Comment: Have you found any solution, I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Anjalijariwala I wound up making changes and exporting the model (dae) from Xcode replacing the underlying file. Xcode would notice the file changed and I would click revert to read the new file from disk. Not pretty but I am out of the weeds.

Answer (score 0):

close all xcode.take dae file to separate folder.Open dae file in xcode you can save without problem.